# How does dotnet choose the dll to use from a package

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a specific issue. My application was complied for .NET Core 2.1, and the internal libraries targeted .Net Standard 2.0. Now, I upgraded the application to .Net 5.0 (the libraries' targets are not changed). Everything works fine as expected except one thing.

One of my nuget dependencies is https://www.nuget.org/packages/prometheus-net.AspNetCore . The project referencing this package targets the `netstandard2.0`. The nuget package has 2 dlls inside of it: for `dotnetapp3.1` and `netstandard2.0`.

After switching to .Net 5.0 application builds, but fails to run properly because of some dependency conflict, it seems:

```
Connection id "0HM4BK8S61SER", Request id "0HM4BK8S61SER:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Enumerator' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at Prometheus.HttpMetrics.CaptureRouteDataMiddleware.TryCaptureRouteData(HttpContext context)
   at Prometheus.HttpMetrics.CaptureRouteDataMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Extensions.MapMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

After some digging, I've figured out that the DLL being used by the running application targets .Net 3.1 and not .Net Standard 2.0 (even though my project targets .Net Standard).

I've tried to manually replace the package dll with the .Net Standard one and indeed it fixes the issue.

Now, the general question is: how `dotnet` chooses which dll from the nuget package to use? Is there a good description or documentation about this process?

The more specific question is: can I make it use the dll I want it to use, specifically the one targeting .Net Standard 2.0?

Comment: [How NuGet resolves package dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution) article may help

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski This article explains perfectly how a version of a package is chosen. But my question is about how a dll inside the chosen package is picked. Both 3.1 and St2.0 dlls are in the same package version (4.0), and I need St2.0 to be used, but the other is selected.